# Bound service won't start

Tags: android

I have spend all day dealing with this problem, I can't solve it. I am exhausted ,have no ideas what to do with it. Please help.
I want to create service that plays music in background.But receiving always null instead of service. Sometimes onServiceConnected is called, sometimes not

```
 public class SoundService extends Service {
        private IBinder myBinder = new MyLocalBinder() ;
        private static boolean isSoundOn = false;
        private static boolean isBgMusicOn = false;
        private static int[] soundPoolIds = null;
        private Context appContext = null;
        private static SoundPlayer instance = null;
        private MediaPlayer mp = null;
        private SoundPool sndPool = null;   

public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder {
            public SoundService getService() {
                return SoundService.this;
            }
    }
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return myBinder;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        //  initSoundPools();

        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.onUnbind(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onRebind(intent);
        }
        public long getCurrentTime() {
            Time time = new Time();
            time.setToNow();

            return time.toMillis(false);

        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        } 
        private void initBackground() {
            //Some magic code here

        }
        private void playMusic(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Some magic code here

        }
        private boolean musicIsPlaying(MediaPlayer mp)  {

    //Some magic code here

       }
             return false;
        }
        public void stopPlayingBackground() {
        //Some magic code here
        }
        private void stopPlaying(MediaPlayer mp,boolean release) {
            //Some magic code here
            }
        private int randInt(int min, int max) {

           //Some magic code here
        }
        private void initSoundPools() {
        //Some magic code here
        }
        public void turnSoundOn(boolean on) {
            isSoundOn = on;
        }
        public void turnMusicOn(boolean on) {
            isBgMusicOn = on;
        }
        public void playBackgroundMusic() {
        //Some magic code here
        }
        public void playSoundFx(int id) {
            //Some magic code here
        }
        }

    }
```

Here is Class that extends another that in turn extends Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends LGame  {
    p
    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";

    private static SoundService soundService;
    private static boolean isBound = false;
    private Thread serviceThread;
    private ServiceConnection myConnection;
    @Override
    public void onGamePaused() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onGameResumed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        }
        if (soundService!=null) {
            soundService.stopSelf();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public static SoundService getSoundService() {
        return soundService;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMain() {
        LTexture.ALL_LINEAR = true;
        LSetting setting = new LSetting();
        setting.width = 800;
        setting.height = 480;
        setting.fps = 30;
        setting.landscape = true;
        setting.showFPS = false;
        myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
                MyLocalBinder binder = (MyLocalBinder) service;
                soundService = binder.getService();
                isBound = true;
            } 

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                isBound = false;
            }

           };
        serviceThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundService.class);
                getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            }
            };
            serviceThread.start();

        register(setting, MainGame.class);


    }
```

Firstly I tried to start service in main thread but nothing changed in both cases.
Of course I've declared service in manifest.
I hope someone can help me with this.
Thx for help in advance. 
**EDIT**
I have mentioned that I have already tried to start it like in your post but nothing changed

**HELP !! I have tried almost everything**

Comment: To the editor who changed it to 'Sound Service' - NO . It's a Bound service, that's why it has an onBind and an IBinder.

Answer (score 0):

You should never bind a service in different thread, if you want to do async tasks you should create the threads inside the service itself.

```
@Override
public void onMain() {
    LTexture.ALL_LINEAR = true;
    LSetting setting = new LSetting();
    setting.width = 800;
    setting.height = 480;
    setting.fps = 30;
    setting.landscape = true;
    setting.showFPS = false;
    myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            MyLocalBinder binder = (MyLocalBinder) service;
            soundService = binder.getService();
            isBound = true;
        } 

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            isBound = false;
        }

       };
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundService.class);
    getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    register(setting, MainGame.class);


}
```

From Android documentation :

> The bindService() method returns **immediately** without a value.

So binding your service in the UI thread will not cause any delaying nor UI freezing.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have already tried to start it like in your post but nothing changed